# How to set the Description for an AWS CacheCluster using CloudFormation?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-elasticache

I would like to set the Description for a Redis ElastiCache CacheCluster as part of a CloudFormation template - how is this achieved?

The Description value is visible in the AWS console Cluster details section for the cache cluster and I can modify it manually here, but would prefer to set the description at the time the resource is created via CloudFormation.

Answer (score 0):

What you see in the console is `replicationGroupDescription`.

See docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticache-replicationgroup.html).

Here is an evidence from CloudTrail when creating a cluster
CreateReplicationGroupInfo event:

```
{
    "eventVersion": "1.08",
    "userIdentity": {
        "type": "AssumedRole",
        "principalId": "AROAQT5F43NHFZQUQD6ZH:vasyl.herman",
        "arn": "arn:aws:sts::042760723278:assumed-role/AWSReservedSSO_AWSAdministratorAccess_40654debbaf500f7/vasyl.herman",
        "accountId": "042760723278",
        "accessKeyId": "ASIAQT5F43NHHIRZJ6NT",
        "sessionContext": {
            "sessionIssuer": {
                "type": "Role",
                "principalId": "AROAQT5F43NHFZQUQD6ZH",
                "arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/aws-reserved/sso.amazonaws.com/AWSReservedSSO_AWSAdministratorAccess_40654debbaf500f7",
                "accountId": "123456789012",
                "userName": "AWSReservedSSO_AWSAdministratorAccess_40654debbaf500f7"
            },
            "webIdFederationData": {},
            "attributes": {
                "creationDate": "2023-07-11T10:35:47Z",
                "mfaAuthenticated": "false"
            }
        }
    },
    "eventTime": "2023-07-11T10:39:30Z",
    "eventSource": "elasticache.amazonaws.com",
    "eventName": "CreateReplicationGroup",
    "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
    "sourceIPAddress": "91.207.210.227",
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "requestParameters": {
        "replicationGroupId": "test",
        ###### ++++++ HERE ++++++ ######
        "replicationGroupDescription": "test Easy created demo cluster on 2023-07-11T10:39:00.284Z",
        "automaticFailoverEnabled": true,
        "multiAZEnabled": false,
        "numNodeGroups": 1,
        "replicasPerNodeGroup": 0,
        "cacheNodeType": "cache.t4g.micro",
        "networkType": "ipv4",
        "engine": "redis",
        "engineVersion": "7.0",
        "cacheParameterGroupName": "default.redis7.cluster.on",
        "cacheSubnetGroupName": "test",
        "securityGroupIds": [
            "sg-09af0b87ec8f2a686"
        ],
        "tags": [],
        "port": 6379,
        "autoMinorVersionUpgrade": true,
        "transitEncryptionEnabled": false,
        "atRestEncryptionEnabled": true
    },
    "responseElements": {
        "replicationGroupId": "test",
        "description": "test Easy created demo cluster on 2023-07-11T10:39:00.284Z",
        "globalReplicationGroupInfo": {},
        "status": "creating",
        "pendingModifiedValues": {},
        "memberClusters": [
            "test-0001-001"
        ],
        "automaticFailover": "enabled",
        "multiAZ": "disabled",
        "snapshotRetentionLimit": 0,
        "snapshotWindow": "09:00-10:00",
        "clusterEnabled": true,
        "cacheNodeType": "cache.t4g.micro",
        "transitEncryptionEnabled": false,
        "atRestEncryptionEnabled": true,
        "aRN": "arn:aws:elasticache:us-east-1:123456789012[![enter image description here][2]][2]:replicationgroup:test",
        "deleteProtection": false,
        "logDeliveryConfigurations": [],
        "replicationGroupCreateTime": "Jul 11, 2023 10:39:30 AM",
        "dataTiering": "disabled",
        "autoMinorVersionUpgrade": true,
        "networkType": "ipv4",
        "ipDiscovery": "ipv4",
        "clusterMode": "enabled"
    },
    "requestID": "2a6b7040-0bf4-4175-a6eb-c00e56f54ac5",
    "eventID": "36e72a57-3125-4de5-854b-210a15353600",
    "readOnly": false,
    "eventType": "AwsApiCall",
    "managementEvent": true,
    "recipientAccountId": "123456789012",
    "eventCategory": "Management",
    "tlsDetails": {
        "tlsVersion": "TLSv1.2",
        "cipherSuite": "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256",
        "clientProvidedHostHeader": "elasticache.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "sessionCredentialFromConsole": "true"
}
```

and [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOsNH.png)

Hope it helps!